# Compute Big-O for a program in Java

Tags: java, time, big-o, complexity-theory

I just would like to ask that what is Big-O for this program. I think It's `n/2`, but I am not sure.

```
public static boolean isPrime(int k) {
    if (k <= 1)
        return false;
    else if (k > 2 && k%2 == 0)
        return false;
    else 
    {
        for(int i = 3;i<=k/2;i+=2)
            if (k % i == 0)
                return false;
    }
    return true;
}
```

Comment: one loop with "simple" boundary conditions and increments => O(n) *(= O(n/2) )*.

Comment: "*I think It's n/2*" - constants are neglected in big-O notation, and since `n/2 = 1/2 * n`, it would actually be `= O(n)`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The complexity is `O(k)` which is **linear time**.

Take the worst case execution where `k` is a **prime**. Then your algorithm will execute all lines until the `return true;`.

Particularly you completely execute the `for` loop which yields `(k / 4) - 3` iterations:

```
for (int i = 3; i <= k/2; i += 2)
```

So you get `O((k / 4) - 3)` which is `O(k)`.

Comment: `<pedantic>` while not wrong, the "proper notation" would be `f(k) = k/2  ∈ O(n)` =) (depending on the definition or convention used, you can replace the `∈` with `=`)`</pedantic>`

Comment: Well, `O(k / 2) = O(k)` is correct. Both denote the same sets. But I get what you want to say :)

Comment: Only k/4 elements will be examined, not k/2.

Comment: @A.H. You are correct, didn't see the `i += 2`. Edited.

Comment: As @Zabuza hinted, every `f(x) = c * x` with `c ∈ ℝ⁺` maps to the same function-set when passed to the `O`-function. Thus `O(k/4) = O(k/2) = O(k)` ^^